# Devise add to password change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I would like to change a simple attribute to the user after they change their password.

I have an attribute on users called "password_changed" with a default of false, but would like to change this to true after they change their password. Is the only way to do this to create a custom Devise password edit? Like this (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password). Or can I extend the update method on the devise registrations controller with something like:

```
def update
current_user.password_changed = true
current_user.save
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `after_save` callback for your `User` model:

```
after_save :password_changed_callback, if: Proc.new { |record| record.persisted? && record.password_changed? }
```

Comment: Where does this belong? On the RegistrationController update method?

Comment: No, it's callback for your User model. The better way is use perform this operation on model level.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mind taking a sec to explain what this line does?

Comment: Not at all. You will be better to read some documentation about callbacks. You can start from this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: To me this looks like it will call the callback method of "password_changed_callback" after every save on the User model. I dont know what the if statement does

Comment: This callback will fire if model object is persisted and password attribute changed.

Comment: record.password_changed? is an actual method?